# Is there a way to explicitly mutate the established control flow type of a variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I know we can use the `as` keyword to inline assert types where they are needed. But what I'm trying to do here is to mutate the type of a variable in a code block such that the type persists until the block exits. I want to do this without creating separate variables and ideally without [runtime assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

#### Summary of Requirements

- No `as` keyword type assertions
- No creation of separate variable
- [No runtime assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)

#### Example

Something I'm trying to write is a `setProps` method that sets the properties of an object via a single function. The function is typed generically so that the right prop-to-value type is enforced. Inside the function is a large `switch` statement that handles each property separately and each property may need access to the value multiple times (hence why I don't want to do `as` assertions because it requires repetition).

Even more ideally I'd like TypeScript to infer the types of my values in the switch statement implicitly. But I don't think it's possible today.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
interface Props {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  enrolled: boolean;
}

const props: Props = {
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  enrolled: false,
};

export function setProp<K extends keyof Props>(prop: K, value: Props[K]): void {
  const propName: keyof Props = prop; // This is needed because TypeScript can't break down the union within type K
  switch (propName) {
    case 'name':
      props.name = value;
      // ^-- Error!
      // Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      //   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
      break;
    case 'age':
      props.age = value;
      // ^-- Same error!
      break;
    case 'enrolled':
      props.enrolled = value;
      // ^-- Same error!
      break;
  }
}

// Prop name and value type combination are enforced by TypeScript
setProp('name', 'John');
setProp('age', 20);
setProp('enrolled', true);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAsAFDLIhwC2EAXMjmFKAOYDcJZczt5ArpQCNo7UsgghMAG0kQAJnQEYMMuCBEBfEiQQYQDZFky466bHgC8BDuSo8A5HYA01rjwAMz0eKkz5yeJI4EJ7qIiQQAB5YGFBg-rwgCGDAuvQQYKZYADwA0mIRkCCyeADWEACeGDBoRjgAfAAUhth0OY7IAG5wkrw8mTgA2jkAugCUdB0YwLJWojp6cc1YAHK2dGWV1f3IlkusyAD0B8gAKgAWwHiX5BBycshCCHC8QaflWBAAyghMWHFPIDscQEUAgcBKyFkGAA7iBkGAzigEik4dDgAjQPD3igctYcGiwAgzsgmkZVtRRrMyGQnq87BRqHYaNZqQZagA6BkoSxdHoQESsshHZAAPQAtGLkABRKCYKAAQhZ1OFJ2xyDsDCYIGYyAAPnxBNA9Q8lCpAchriAMHE4DgcMBmBQBDJ4RgsR91ZqWHZ2UqhccyKqPfT+EIoHYLXgrTa7Q6nS6wG6wGqNYxveyGgAmADMmczoz9D1B4IF1NpKDsriZhaWOHZrh2nW6vVLrOF4sln1sYllMUVolZILBJVbyHL6u8yl81YH1Nr7Mn0nuPOb-ML7YlyC71B7cv7gqLw9LmmIJ5IwsyNh3qhmvN67pQOkEoDgyVScFBYhAMBiSBmAnKN4Pm+X4wBIIIMiMBp6VsJx1QAKQwM5AVGEQIMyaCq3aTM3FQ8D0gwuxF2ndpGF6VCgA)

#### A close solution

The closest solution I came up with is to use a completely unchecked runtime assertion and rely on the tree shaking/dead-code elimination present in many bundlers today to remove them:

```
export function uncheckedAssert<T>(value: unknown): asserts value is T {
  return;
}
```

The function can then be re-written as:

```
export function setProp<K extends keyof Props>(prop: K, value: Props[K]): void {
  const propName: keyof Props = prop; // This is needed because TypeScript can't break down the union within type K
  switch (propName) {
    case 'name':
      uncheckedAssert<Props[typeof propName]>(value);
      props.name = value;
      // ^-- No error!
      break;
    case 'age':
      uncheckedAssert<Props[typeof propName]>(value);
      props.age = value;
      // ^-- No error!
      break;
    case 'enrolled':
      uncheckedAssert<Props[typeof propName]>(value);
      props.enrolled = value;
      // ^-- No error!
      break;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAsAFDLIhwC2EAXMjmFKAOYDcJZczt5ArpQCNo7UsgghMAG0kQAJnQEYMMuCBEBfEiQQYQDZFky466bHgC8BDuSo8A5HYA01rjwAMz0eKkz5yeJI4EJ7qIiQQAB5YGFBg-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-D12gAJjcEDiDfcCKwkKs5B-Rhejg8IohiOIYHZE84XrP1eX5ZsshObs5ToBIShAGEQHGTdSNiPAd2uE4qWQUEwF4KA1BIRcgA)

Comment: No, this is not currently possible, see [ms/TS#10421](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10421). TS's current solutions are the ones you have found and rejected. (It's not clear to me why you want this, is it just preference? Or is there something specifically bad that happens if you have an extra variable or an extra function call?)  Does this fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: @jcalz Specifically I'm writing software for embedded devices with limited CPU and memory so I stay particularly conscious of areas where TypeScript requires runtime hacks to achieve something that theoretically could be handled at compile time. Additionally there's a small amount of cognitive complexity, imo, involved in creating a new variable for each property since it needs a name which can either be redundant or just unintuitive. But, as always, your commentary and link to the relevant issue on GH is a great help! That works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of TypeScript 4.9 there is no built-in type assertion operator which acts at the block scope level the way you want.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#10421](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10421) for the relevant feature request.  The workarounds for this are pretty much those you already found.

The use case of being able to narrow some variable's apparent type this way is essentially covered by [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).  As mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695#issuecomment-518952880) on the pull request that introduced them:

> It definitely would be nice to be able to explicitly assert a control flow type for a variable instead of having to cast on each reference. You *can* get the same effect with a call to an `asserts` function, but of course that call ends up in the emitted code. Still, JavaScript VMs are pretty decent at reducing away the cost of calls to empty functions.

Most of the requests for this are closed as duplicates of ms/TS#10421, with the note that assertion functions are the preferred solution.  So I'd say it's unlikely that anything will change here in the near future.  Still, anyone who's interested in seeing this might want to give that issue a  and/or leave a comment that describes their use case and why assertion functions don't suffice.